# Exposing EJB as REST service packed into EAR module (no WAR)

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, wildfly, ejb-3.1

i'm new to Java RESTful development and i need to implement some REST services on top of existing 3.1 EJBs.

I have an existing enterprise application which consists of an ejb-jar and some other jars packed into an EAR and deployed into Wildfly 10.

I've seen many examples out there where a WAR module is used and the class `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` is used as well.
I am aware of using annotations like `Path` etc. on my resource classes.

But my question is: can i build these REST services from my existing EJBs without using a WAR ? I would like to keep my modules unchanged (just EAR with ejb-jar).

Thank you so much.

Comment: EJBs can certainly be used directly as REST endpoints, but I'm not sure if there are packaging requirements. You should try it out and see.

Comment: The problem is that most jaxrs implementations, uses servlet under the hood, which requires war packaging, at least for java-ee

Comment: @vortex.alex Did you find an answer to your problem? I got exactly the same question.

Comment: @noircc Unfortunately no, after maress comment I decided not to waste too much time and I created a separate WAR.

Comment: Yeah, I also think it's not possible after endless trial and error.